# log4net duplicate entries

Tags: log4net

I'm new to log4net and been reading and reading and come to no conclusion of what my problem is.
Here is the configuration:

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
</root>

<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Server=XXXXX;Database=XXX;Network=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX" />
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
  <commandText value="dbo.LogWrite" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@LogDate" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@LogLevel" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserID" />
    <dbType value="Int32" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%property{UserID}" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

When I go to a .NET page and in Page_Load this statement executes:

`log.Error("hi")`

i get this error as an entry in my database table. But if i go to this page again rather quickly i get a total of 3 entries? It seemes that if i wait ~10sec before reloading the page i get only one more entry. I have set the buffersize to 1. Anyone who had the same problem? The most part of the community tends to say that if there is a problem then it's most likely in your configuration but to me me my configuration looks fine.

Greatly appreciate any who can shed som lights over this!

//Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Log4Net is probably working just fine.  It is logging what is happening.

You need to figure out why Page_Load is executing when you don't expect it.

Comment: I see now that there is nothing wrong with the configuration. Somehow my page_load runs twice and need to understand why. Thanks, i will solve it from here!